# how do I create a unary many to many relationship in my sql

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I know how to create a many to many relationship, but I'm specifically looking for a UNARY many to many relationship. Any ideas or tutorials I can view? Or really good explanation?

Comment: Can you discuss the structure of the tables involved (i.e. the subject table and the join table)?

Comment: Can you link to a definition of a unary many to many relationship?

Comment: "Unary" as in "opposite of binary"? I.e. a single table in a (many-to-many) relationship with itself?

Answer (score 1):

Really doing a many-to-many unary relationship is not really much different than a binary many-to-many relationship.  You would still need a join table to express the many to many relationship, however the columns of this join table would both relate back to the single subject table.

A classic example of this might be the case of product bundles in an e-commerce setting, where the product bundle might have it's own product id, but also be related to a set of products included in that bundle.  Of course any product might be bundled in any fashion (thus many-to-many relationship).  The table structure might look like this:

```
product
---------
product_id (primary_key)
product_name
...other product attributes

bundle
---------
product_id (foreign key to product table)
product_component (also a foreign key to product table)
....any bundle specific attributes not derivable from component attributes
```

Similarly relationships between users (i.e. "friends", "likes", etc.) in an app might also be expressed in a similar manner.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with many-to-many You will need join table. e.g:

You have 5 tables: TblA, TblB, TblC, TblD, TblE

Each of them has id as PK.

You create join table with fields:

Aid, Bid, Cid, Did, Eid